# Создание БД (PhoneGap)

Tags: phonegap, android, javascript

Подскажите мне пожалуйста как делать проверку на существование БД, что бы она не создавалась при каждом открытии страницы. Вот пример с документации:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

//Событие на загрузку страницы
function onDeviceReady() {
    var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);
    db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
}

//Создание БД
function populateDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, name, image)');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, name, image) VALUES (1, "Konstantin",     "avatar.png")');
}
```

При таком раскладе при каждом новом открытии страницы БД сразу удаляется ну а потом создается заново. Подскажите куда мне капать ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Убрать tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO'); и в последнюю добавить IF NO EXIST
??или я чего то не понимаю

Comment: При удалении строки `tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');`
Выдает ошибку, не создается БД, а что вы имеете в виду в последнюю добавить `IF NO EXIST ` в какую последнюю, можно по точней, а то я чего то не догоняю.

Comment: не создаётся БД?странно..Команда DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO удаляет таблицу демо в БД если она существует.Как минимум минус удаление.
Вторая строка создаёт таблицу если не существует её//
вынесите внесение данных в другую функцию вообще:
function populateDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, name, image)');
    var flag=1;
}
function addInfo(){
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, name, image) VALUES (1, "Konstantin",     "avatar.png")');
}

а потом после применения функции populateDB делаешь
if(flag==1){
addInfo();
}

Comment: Ща проверим !

Comment: Вообщем то все работает, спасибо !!!

Comment: на здоровье)